# How do I correctly create a flask sqlalchemy many to many relationship with multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relational-database, flask-sqlalchemy

In the Flask sqlalchemy documentation an example of using a simple many to many relationship is given:

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('page_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('page.id'))
)

class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
        backref=db.backref('pages', lazy='dynamic'))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Where one can use the following syntax to reach out to the related objects:

```
Page.tags
```

What I am trying to accomplish is basically to add the relationship below to the one above:

```
tag_children = db.Table('tag_children,',
                        db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.tag_id')),
                        db.Column('child_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.tag_id'))
                        )
```

So that each page has tags attached to it, but each tag can have multiple children in the scope of that page. I've made a show case for a Page called **cars** below where I have it's tags and their respective children tags.

(Page) Cars:

- Mercedes

  - A-series
  - B-series
  - C-series
- Tesla

  - Tesla Roadster
  - Model X
  - Model S
  - Model 3

*All the list items above are tag objects*

I want to be able to use the following syntax bellow to get the related objects:

```
Page.tag.children
```

For instance (obvously dummy code below, but I want to be clear about what the intended purpose of the relationship is):

```
Cars.tesla.children
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't need another table for `tag_children`. Try to use [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html) Adjacency Lists:

```
class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'))
    children = relationship("Tag",
                backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
            )
```

With this schema you may use syntax like:

```
for tag in page.tags:  # where page is a Page instance received from db
    print tag.children
```

It is a common syntax for working with SQLAlchemy models. Try to use it instead of the proposed `Cars.tesla.children`.

Something like `Cars['tesla'].children` may be implemented via [**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method, but i think, it's very unclear way.

Full code snippet:

```
class Page(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'page'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256))
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary='tags',
        backref=backref('pages', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Tag(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'))
    children = relationship(
        "Tag",
        backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tags(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True)
    page_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('page.id'), primary_key=True)
```

And test case:

```
# Create page and tags
session.add(Page(id=1, name="cars"))
session.add(Tag(id=1, name="Mercedes"))
session.add(Tag(id=2, name="A-series", parent_id=1))
session.add(Tag(id=3, name="B-series", parent_id=1))
session.add(Tag(id=4, name="C-series", parent_id=1))
session.add(Tag(id=5, name="Tesla"))
session.add(Tag(id=6, name="Tesla Roadster", parent_id=5))
session.add(Tag(id=7, name="Model X", parent_id=5))
session.add(Tag(id=8, name="Model S", parent_id=5))
session.add(Tag(id=9, name="Model 3", parent_id=5))

# Fill relation
session.add(Tags(tag_id=1, page_id=1))
session.add(Tags(tag_id=5, page_id=1))

session.commit()

print session.query(Page).get(1)  # >>> cars
print session.query(Page).get(1).tags  # >>> Mercedes, Tesla
print session.query(Page).get(1).tags[1].children  # >>> Tesla models
```

Comment: The problem is that the tags children shall be in the scope of the page only. For instance the tag Tesla should only have those specific children in that one page.

It doesn't seem that there is any restriction in your example. I'm thinking that there must be some kind of composite primary key, or something?

Comment: no, i think, you don't need to composit keys here. see my updated answer and check whether it right for you